# AngularJS filter by search and check filtered values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app i use something similar to this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/vefoqofuzo/1/edit?html,js,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="listsModule">
    <div ng-controller="listsController">

      <input type="text" id="filter_lists" class="form-control" ng-model="search"
                           placeholder="Search a list">

      <table class="table table-hover ng-cloak table-condensed ng-cloak">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAll"/></th>
                        <th>List name</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="list in lists | filter:search | orderBy:'name'"
                        ng-click="selectCheckbox(list)">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="list.isSelected" ng-checked="checkAll"></td>
                        <td>{{ list.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ list.isSelected }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>


    </div>
  </div>



</body>
</html>
```

and js:

```
var app = angular.module('listsModule', []);

app.controller('listsController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.lists = [
    {"id": 39, "name": "list1", "isSelected": false}, 
    {"id": 40, "name": "list2", "isSelected": false}
]

});
```

but i have one trouble...

What would be if i will have huge ammounts of data? Filter is not the best practice... So for performance i use ng-show. But then i have question: how to select only visible values with selectAll button?

http://jsbin.com/curifaliqa/1/edit?html,js,output

So i don't use filter: becouse it affect on performance, instead i use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="listsModule">
    <div ng-controller="listsController">
      <div ng-click="selectAll()" style="background:red">Select all!</div>
      <input type="text" id="filter_lists" class="form-control" ng-model="search"
                           placeholder="Search a list">

      <table class="table table-hover ng-cloak table-condensed ng-cloak">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAll"/></th>
                        <th>List name</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="list in lists | orderBy:'name'" ng-show="([list] | filter:search).length > 0"
                        ng-click="selectCheckbox(list)">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="list.isSelected" ng-checked="checkAll"></td>
                        <td>{{ list.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ list.isSelected }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>


    </div>
  </div>



</body>
</html>
```

**and how now i could deal with only shown elements? not with all of them... ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i do so: i still use ng-show but i'm using watcher to get filtered array:

```
  $scope.$watch('search', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    $scope.filteredArray = $filter('filter')($scope.users, newVal);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

How about apply this filter one again in javascript, like this:

```
var arrayAfterFilter = $scope.lists.filter(
    function(list, index) {
        var result = $filter('filter')([list], $scope.search);
        return result.length;
    }
);
```

The jsbin link : http://jsbin.com/qemotufeva/1/edit?html,js,output

Edit: I update selectAll function a little bit, so it will ignore item that doesn't match the search text

```
$scope.selectAll = function(){
        angular.forEach($scope.lists, function(item) {
          var result = $filter('filter')([item], $scope.search);
          if(result.length) {
            item.isSelected = true;  
          }          
        });
  };
```

http://jsbin.com/seqabevoxu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: didn't understand what you mean) maybe change it in jsBin?

Comment: hm: load page -> put in search button 1 -> click select all -> delete 1 from input. All items are selected. Not that i need... after that only list1 must be checked

Comment: I try to make some change in jsbin, hope I do it right. Click the "click me" button to see in console log on filtered array.

Comment: it didn't work. Here is video. After all only one list1 must be selected, but actually 2 are. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/CapturedMovie006_converted.avi

Comment: Well, sorry I can't guarantee that. To have good performance, I recommend to use some other component like ng-grid instead of ng-repeat.  Hope someone else will have a better solution